# ¿Cómo mostrar un div sin contenido?

Tags: html

Mi duda es cómo puedo mostrar un bloque `div` sin que éste tenga contenido ninguno, ni texto ni nada. Estoy probando a hacer un layout de html pero no quiero incluir ningún contenido.

Comment: basta con ponerle un **width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red;** los 200px son sólo referencial

Comment: Hola Hugo, ¿Que has intentado? Existen varias formas de hacerlo pero sin un contexto o un ejemplo de lo que has intentado y en que fallas la pregunta es demasiado amplia

Comment: como el amigo arriba dijo, debes setear `width` y `height` para que tenga un tamaño y para poder verlo puedes setear `border`o `background-color`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos la referencia del código que te anexo es meramente como ejemplo pues depende totalmente de la construcción propia de tu sitio web:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <style>
        #lienzo{
            background-color: steelblue;
            width: 350px;
            height: 350px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="lienzo">
      
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Se le agregan tanto la propiedad width como height ya que un div es un elemento que por defecto necesita de un contenido que le de dimensiones, entonces si yo le quito dichas medidas pierde proporción y desconoce el motor de render del navegador que dimensiones darle.

Los estilos son meramente opcionales tenerlos directamente en el HTML pudieras colocarlos en un css por separado y vincularlo al HTML

Answer (score 2):

Solo necesitas especificar el background-color, width y height

.hola{
   Width: 100%;
   Heigth: 150px;
   Background-color: gray;
}